# Change of Variable when integrating over a line in 2D

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was supposed to calculate Flux of $F$ (a vector field in $\mathbb R^2)$ over $C$ (boundary of the unit circle) using Green's Theorem

It turned out to be $$\int_C ax \,dy$$ where $a$ is a constant. The question then suggested to apply change of variable formulae but I'm not sure how since Jacobian method cannot be applied (there is only $dy$, not $dxdy$). I know the unit circle can be parametrized by a single variable. Do I just replace $x$ with $cos(t)$ and $dy$ with $d(sin(t))$ and integrate over $t=0,2\pi$?

Further, say $A$ (a surface in $R^3$) can be parametrized by 2 variables only, how do I do change on variable on the following Integral?
$$\int_A f(x,y)dxdz$$

Answer (score 1):

The somewhat disappointing answer is that it depends on what $A$ looks like. Integration on $C$ is easy, because $C\setminus \{1\}\simeq (0,2\pi)$ and the set $\{1\}$ has measure $0$. Hence, 
$$
\int_C ax\textrm{d}y=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} a \cos(t)\textrm{d}t,
$$
if by $dy$, you mean the usual surface measure and by $x$ you mean the Euclidean $x$-coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For a Riemannian $2$-manifold, $A$, you can only really hope to do change of variables in a given chart (in the situation above, we had one chart that covered almost all of $C$). Once you're in a chart, you can borrow the usual change of variables theorem from $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: what is a 'chart'? and do you mean $a\cos^2(t)$? (That is what I was getting if I just substituted $x$ with $\cos(t)$ and $dy$ with $d(\sin(t))=cos(t)dt$. Also, since I'm assuming $A$ can be parametrized by $2$ variables, doesn't it mean $A\equiv [0,1]^2$?

Comment: Basically: I don't think there is a good, rigorous answer to this that doesn't involve concept of a manifold (whether explicitly or implicitly.)

Comment: And if your $dy$ measure should mean $\sin(t)dt$, then you would, indeed, get $a\cos^2$ as your integrand.